# How to do unit testing of Modal in react using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
// Delete.jsx

import React, {useCallback, useRef} from "react"
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import {ModalComponent, modalOpen} from "../Modal"

export function Delete () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const modalRef = useRef(null)
    const handleDelete = () => {
        dispatchEvent(deleteData())
        modalRef.current.close
    }
    return (
        <Type>
            <Button
                onClick={modalOpen(modalRef)}
            >
                Delete
            </Button>
            <ModalComponent func={handleDelete} refer={modalRef} />
        </Type>
    )
}
```

```
// ModalComponent.jsx

import React, {useCallback} from "react"

export function ModalComponent (props) {
    const modalRef = props.refer

    return (
        <Modal
            ref={modalRef}
            onClose={modalClose(modalRef)}
            >
                <Type>
                    Are you sure ?
                </Type>
                <Type>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                        <Button
                            id='DeleteButton'
                            onClick={modalClose(modalRef)}
                        >
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            onClick={props.func}
                        >
                            Confirm
                        </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </Type>
            </Modal>
    )
}

export const modalOpen = (refModal) => {
    return useCallback(
        () => {
            refModal.current.open()
        }, [refModal]
    )
}

export const modalClose = (refModal) => {
    return useCallback(
        () => {
            refModal.current.close()
        }, [refModal]
    )
}
```

Above are the codes of Delete and ModalComponent, I'm trying to write unit test cases for Delete Button.

```
// Delete.test.js

import React from "react"
import {fireEvent, render} from "@testing-library/react"
import * as modal from '../ModalComponent'

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useDispatch: jest.fn()
}))

describe('Delete button', () => {
    it('should open modal when delete button is called', () => {
        const modalSpy = jest.spyOn(modal, 'modalOpen').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
        const component = render(
            <Delete />
        )
        const button = component.container.querySelector('#DeleteButton')
        fireEvent.click(button)
        expect(modalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

Here what I tried to test if modal is opening or not and it's working but I want to test Delete funcationality but here I've mocked the modal so I'm not sure how to test the handle delete and when I tried without mocking the modal it throws error.

Could somebody please help me to handle modal events so I can test handle edit ?

Comment: It is normal to mock in this example you should think about using a ref what you've done so far is good.

Comment: Basic rule: don't mock the "thing" you are trying to test. What exactly are you wanting, or trying, to unit test here? From what I can tell you are accessing internal implementation details of the modal and in doing so basically violate the testing strategy that React-Testing-Library wants to use, e.g. testing components/code using their APIs, i.e. their public interfaces like props and rendered UI. The `modalOpen` and `modalClose` functions also break the Rules of Hooks by calling `useCallback` in a callback function, you should almost ***certainly*** have React hook errors regarding this.

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah you're right that if I want to test the modal I shouldn't mock it, but without mocking I'm getting an error when Delete is rendered. I want to test if dispatch is called when delete is pressed. Do you have any idea how to do it without mocking modal ?

Comment: @MoussaBistami Should I try to mock useRef ?

Comment: @DrewReese So I tried without mocking modal, when I click the Delete button using fireEvent and expect modalOpen toHaveBeenCalled then it throws error stating received value must be a mock or spy function

Comment: @DrewReese Modal is imported from React

Comment: @DrewReese there is a Blueprint of React that our institute uses from there only I've imported all the React components like Modal, Type, Button etc. It is not available publically.

Comment: @DrewReese Is it not possible to do unit testing of the existing code that I have? I Can't change the source code

Comment: @DrewReese Apologies, as a blueprint is not publically available I'm unable to share the code of components. Is there any way to handle the useRef

Comment: I could create another modal component that ***does*** expose open/close handlers on a ref, but with the other issues you have with the code I'm not sure it's worth it. Trying to use these React refs like this basically goes against conventional React practices, and trying to expose out "internal" functions for testing is also an anti-pattern. I'm working on a sandbox now with what little code you've provided with the hopes of getting a passing test that tests clicking the delete button and asserting that a modal opened.

Comment: @DrewReese In the docs of the blueprint it is stated that Modals can be opened and closed using the ref you pass to the modal. You should use open and close function calling `modalRef.current.open()` and `modalRef.current.close()`, where `modalRef` is the ref you pass into the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

Don't mock what you are trying to unit test. Your unit tests should mirror how users or other components interact with the component, e.g. via its rendered UI and props.

## Suggestion

Since you can't share the `Modal` component I've created a mock modal component that exposes out open and close handlers via a React ref.

Mock Modal component:

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useState
} from "react";

const Modal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      open: () => setOpen(true),
      close: () => setOpen(false)
    }),
    []
  );

  return open ? (
    <div data-testid="modal">
      <button type="button" onClick={props.onClose}>
        x
      </button>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
});
```

Delete

```
const modalOpen = (refModal) => () => {
  refModal.current.open();
};

const modalClose = (refModal) => () => {
  refModal.current.close();
};

export default function Delete() {
  // const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const modalRef = useRef(null);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    // dispatchEvent(deleteData())
    modalRef.current.close();
  };

  return (
    <Type>
      <Button onClick={modalOpen(modalRef)}>Delete</Button>
      <ModalComponent func={handleDelete} refer={modalRef} />
    </Type>
  );
}
```

Delete unit test

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Delete from "./Delete";

describe("Delete button", () => {
  it("should open modal when delete button is called", () => {
    const { queryByText, queryByTestId } = render(<Delete />);

    // Assert that the modal is not current in the DOM
    expect(queryByTestId("modal")).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    // Click delete button to toggle the modal open
    fireEvent.click(queryByText("Delete"));

    // Assert that the modal is now in the DOM
    expect(queryByTestId("modal")).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Click modal's close button to toggle the modal closed
    fireEvent.click(queryByText("Close"));

    // Assert that the modal is not current in the DOM
    expect(queryByTestId("modal")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

[image]

When you update your code and uncomment the `useDispatch` hook and `dispatch` call you'll need to also create a Redux store for the test.

Basic example:

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "../path/to/rootReducer";
import Delete from "./Delete";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});

const Providers = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
);

describe("Delete button", () => {
  it("should open modal when delete button is called", () => {
    const { .... } = render(<Delete />, { wrapper: Providers });

    ... testing code ...
  });
});
```

See the Redux [Writing Tests](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) documentation for further general testing information and strategies.